# SQL: How do I search for consecutive events?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostGRES, how can I get all users that had at least 1 "event" three weeks in a row?

**my_events**

```
id  user_id  created_at
------------------------------------------
1   1234     2015-05-05 22:49:18.345787
2   4567     2015-05-05 22:49:30.343386
3   1234     2015-05-05 22:50:16.465029
...
```

**What I've tried:**

Step 1) Get all weeks where a user had an event:

```
SELECT
user_id,
date_part('year', created_at) AS year,
date_part('week', created_at) AS week,
COUNT(1) AS events
FROM my_events
GROUP BY user_id, date_part('year', created_at), date_part('week', created_at)
```

Step 2) Get a count of all weeks where a user had an event:

```
SELECT
user_id,
COUNT(1) AS weeks_with_events
FROM (
  -- Get all weeks where a user had an event.
  SELECT
  user_id,
  date_part('year', created_at) AS year,
  date_part('week', created_at) AS week,
  COUNT(1) AS events
  FROM my_events
  GROUP BY user_id, date_part('year', created_at), date_part('week', created_at)
) a
GROUP BY user_id
```

Unfortunately, this only gives me a count of weeks with an event, it does not check if they were **consecutive** weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are looking at this query:

```
SELECT user_id, date_part('year', created_at) AS yyyy,
       date_part('week', created_at) AS ww, COUNT(8) AS events
FROM my_events
GROUP BY user_id, date_part('year', created_at), date_part('week', created_at);
```

Although not the most general solution, the simplest may be to use `lead()`/`lag()`:

```
with t as (
      SELECT user_id, date_part('year', created_at) AS yy,
             date_part('week', created_at) AS ww, COUNT(8) AS events
      FROM my_events
      GROUP BY user_id, date_part('year', created_at), date_part('week', created_at)
     )
select user_id, ww
from (select t.*,
             lead(ww, 1) over (partition by user_id order by year, ww) as ww1,
             lead(ww, 2) over (partition by user_id order by year, ww) as ww2
      from t
     ) t
where ww1 = ww + 1 and ww2 = ww + 2;
```

This will have problems at the end of the year, because the definition of week of the year starts over again.

EDIT:

To handle the end of year, you would like to do something like `yyyy*52 + ww`.  Alas, that doesn't work for weeks.

Instead, choose an original start date which is on the correct day of the week.  Then count the number of days since that date, divide by 7 and truncate.  This gives you an absolute week number, independent of the year.  From that point, the rest of the query is pretty much the same.

Comment: I just add year times 100 to week number to give a comparison column (just realized the ww+1 and ww+2 is where it will break and this won't help) you need ((year*52)+(ww))+1 = ((nextyear*52)+ww2)

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as 
(SELECT
 user_id,
 date_part('year', created_at) AS year,
 date_part('week', created_at) AS week
 FROM my_events)
, y as (select user_id, year, week as curr, 
   coalesce(lead(week) over(partition by user_id,year order by week),0) as nxt,
  coalesce(lag(week) over(partition by user_id,year order by week),0) as prev 
  from x)
  select distinct user_id 
  from y
  where nxt-curr = 1 and curr-prev = 1
```

You can try this as you need users having atleast one event in 3 consecutive weeks. The premise is that if a user has atleast one event in 3 consecutive weeks, he will have atlease one row where `nxt-curr` and `curr-prev` is 1.